# Modal error dialog

Tags: development, custom-form, error

I would like to modify modal dialog for add/edit list items. Precisely, if i got some error message because user didn't enter correct informations in modal form (I have validators), then - I want to modify autogenerated "Return to web" (error modal dialog) link TO return user to "add/edit dialog with inserted ("bad") data" again instead of get redirected to site url address(if he click that one and only autogenerated link).

Does somebody know which file i need to modify and is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually these pop-up dialogs are either initially hidden divs on the page they pop-up from, or they are regular application pages in the LAYOUTS directory that are retrieved and rendered by JavaScript. So the answer is edit either the source page, or edit the application page. It is possible, but it can feel like a bit of a hack.

Obviously you will want to be editing copies of any out-of-the-box SharePoint pages for the usual reasons.

Just to clarify, by LAYOUTS I mean C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS.

Comment: Thanx, I did small investigation and got the same conclusion.